# How to embed components from a different project?

Tags: android, ios

I have two `projects(p1, p2)` and I want to use `components ( views, classes, ...)` from p2 in p1(e.g.:integration as part of a view). What is the best way to do this on the android and on the ios plattform? On the android plattform I know the possibility to `generate p2 as a library-project and integrate it as jar-file in p1.` But is this recommended, or is there a better way?

**Contstraints:** No communication between two different projects (like in android via intent)
I do not have the sourcecode from p2, because this project comes from another company.

Comment: If you don't have the source code of p2 then how you are planning to use it as a library-project?

Comment: I'm in contact with them and p2 isn't developed already

Comment: @user1430985 if it's not yet developed, then get their source code and use git to update changes.

Comment: @biovamp I don't get the code, otherwise it would be much easier for me.

Answer (score 0):

**If you have source of both projects**

On Android you can mark project as "library" (Project -> Android -> Properties -> check Is library) and then add it project to another project (Project -> Android -> Properties -> Add). **Note** that you're not creating any jar and can use any resources from library project (you can't do it with included jar).

It is recommended (since it's included in ADT by default).

**If not**

Nope.

Comment: I did a small testapp and used only the generated jar-file from the second library-project and it works just fine. But i used only a Button from p2, which triggers a Toast-Message.

Comment: @user1430985 you're able to use code from library. Not resources.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, im getting the the resources(xml, icons,...) from the other commpany too. So i think, this should work. Do you also know the best IOS way to use code from a different project?